# Does Nhibernate CommitAsync wait for all Async CRUD Operations?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, nhibernate

I'm trying to figure out how the `CommitAsync` method in nhibernate works in conjunction with `SaveAsync`, `UpdateAsync`, & `DeleteAsync`

My question is: say i call `SaveAsync`, or `UpdateAsync` multiple times without awaiting them. Then sometime later I call `CommitAsync`. Will `CommitAsync` wait for all of the calls to `SaveAsync` and `UpdateAsync` to finish? Or do i have to await them before calling `CommitAsync`?

I Created the test below and tried saving multiple users without awaiting them then tried to commit using `CommitAsync` to see if any would be missing from the DB or if the count would be off but it seems to work. However, every example I've seen online awaits all of their async CRUD operations before committing.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AsyncTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        var sessionSource = new SessionSource();
        int saveCount = 100000;
        using (var session = sessionSource.CreateSession())
        {
            using (var t = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                SaveMany(saveCount, session);
                await t.CommitAsync();
            }
        }

        int count = 0;
        using (var sessoin = sessionSource.CreateSession())
        {
            count = sessoin.Query<User>().Count();
        }

        Assert.That(count, Is.EqualTo(saveCount));
    }

    public void SaveMany(int count, ISession session)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Save(session);
        }
    }

    private Task<object> Save(ISession session)
    {
        return session.SaveAsync(new User()
        {
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = "saveasync",
            MiddleName = "middle",
            LastName = "last"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the related [source code](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Async/Transaction/AdoTransaction.cs#L48)?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, though I was more looking at the SaveAsync method to see if there was a way they were keeping track of when that was called. i didnt see anything, though the CommitAsync code you linked does do go through handling events and the like before commiting. but i didnt see anything where SaveAsync added to those lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this article: [NHibernate 5: async IO bound operations support](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/nhibernate-async-support/)
you should await all of the `async` methods.

Here I copy the relevant part:
Note that this feature is not intended for *parallelism*, only **non-parallel asynchrony**, so make sure to `await` each call before issuing a new call using the same session.

In other words, don’t do this:

```cs
Task<Customer> task1 = session.GetAsync<Customer>(1);
Task<Customer> task2 = session.GetAsync<Customer>(2);

Customer[] customers = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Do this instead:

```cs
Customer customer1 = await session.GetAsync<Customer>(1);
Customer customer2 = await session.GetAsync<Customer>(2);
```

A quick side note about parallelism versus asynchrony. Parallel execution is a subset of asynchronous execution: every parallel execution is asynchronous, but not every asynchronous execution is parallel.

Executing something asynchronously corresponds to "without blocking the caller". It can be achieved by starting this work immediately, which means it will be done in parallel, or by waiting until the caller is finished with their stuff, which means the work will be executed sequentially, either by the same or another thread. Either way, the job will not block the caller and thus we can say that it will be executed asynchronously.